# Cannot manage Azure DevOps from Work Account, even I am the organization owner

Tags: azure-devops

Currently my organization in Azure DevOps contains two users: myname@mycompany.com (Personal Account) and myname@mycompany.com (Work Account).

myname@mycompany.com (Work Account) is the organization owner. When I log into devops with this account, I cannot do anything without avoid the user being switched to the Personal Account automatically.

The personal account does not have permission to manage users nor change and organization settings. So I am kind of stuck.

My end goal is to link this organization to our Azure Ad tennant, that my Work Account is member of.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the AAD identity of the same email address to access the organization, you first need to check whether the organization is connected to AAD [like this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/connect-organization-to-azure-ad?view=azure-devops#connect-your-organization-to-azure-ad) in the `Azure Active Directory` of the organization settings.

[image]

Secondly, when you log in, please select Work or school account. This happens when you sign in with an email address that's shared by your personal Microsoft account and by your work account or school account.

- Select Work or school account if you used this identity to create
  your organization, or if you previously signed in with this identity.
  Your identity is authenticated by your organization's directory in
  Azure AD, which controls access to your organization.
- Select Personal account if you used your Microsoft account with Azure
  DevOps. Your identity is authenticated by the global directory for
  Microsoft accounts.

In addition, you can open a private or incognito browsing session and sign in, which can avoid the influence of the identity cached by the browser.

Here is the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/faq-azure-access?view=azure-devops) about troubleshooting access via Azure AD you can refer to.

Comment: My organization is not connected to AAD in DevOps. This is my goal. However, when I selected the AAD tenant I get and error message, saying I am not authorized to do that operation. It makes total sense, since the user I am logged is a Personal Account. I cannot reach this page with my Work or school account, even in incognito mode.

Comment: After logging into Azure DevOps with my Work or school account, I can only see I am the owner of the organization. Then, any link I click (projects, setting, etc) I am switched automatically to the Personal Account. I am asked for credentials a couple of times, but I always give Work and School credentials.

Comment: I verified that while using a new browser session in private mode, when I log in DevOps providing my Work account, some redirects seems to happen and then my credentials for the Personal account are requested. Cannot go further without providing them. What could I check?

Comment: You can report this problem on our [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html) forum. Our engineers there will ask you for some private information to better investigate this issue.

Comment: Done. Please refer to this topic: https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/organization-owner-changed-but-cannot-do-much/1334751